# i'm trying to make queue class by c # the why dequeueing function doesn't work?

Tags: c#, arrays, data-structures, queue

**this is the class**
data members and getters and setters:

```
class Queue
{
    int[] data; //array
    int size; //size of array
    int counter; //checker if array is fully or impty
    int first; // first element of array
    int last; // last element of arry
}
```

**fixed size constructor**

```
public Queue(int size) { 
    data = new int[this.size];
    size = this.size;
    counter = 0;
    first = 0;
    last = 0;
}
```

**default constructor**

```
public Queue() { //default constructor
    data = new int[10];
    size = 10;
    counter = 0;
    first = 0;
    last = 0;
}
```

**enqueing function "push"**

```
public bool Enqueue(int num) { 
    bool result;
    if (counter<size)
    {
        data[last] = num;   
        last++;
        if(last == size)
            last = 0;
        counter++;
        return result = true
    }
    else
    {
        return result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

**dequeueing function "pop"**

```
public int Dequeueing() {
    int result=-1;
    // I know that i should make this nullable function but (-1) good at this time

    if (counter>0)
    {
        result = data[first];
        first++;
        if (first==size)
            first = 0;
        counter--;
    }
    return result;
}
```

**on the main it is excute the enqueueing good but dequeueing its (first++)and (counter--) but it doesn't delete first input **
**why it doesn't delete (17)**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Queue q1 = new Queue();
    q1.Enqueue(17);
    q1.Enqueue(20);
    q1.Enqueue(25);
    q1.Enqueue(15);
    q1.Enqueue(14);
    q1.Enqueue(13);
    q1.Dequeueing();        

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Are you just practicing? Because there is a built-in [queue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expectation that once you do `first++;` and `counter--;`, the `data[first]` will be deleted is misplaced. Frankly, if it will somehow cause `data[first]` to be deleted then rest of your code will not work. What that code does is to simply `Dequeue`. The `Queue` bounds are marked using `first` and `last`, with the help of `counter`, so only those things need to change and no array element deletion needs to happen

Let me help you understand your code a bit. Your `Queue` class is what is called a [Circular Queue](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/circular-queue-set-1-introduction-array-implementation/). In such an implementation, you have the benefit that the amount of storage allocated for the `Queue` is "fixed" and determined on construction. This also implies that when you `Enqueue` there will be no extra memory requested and when you `Dequeue` there will be no memory released.

If you wish to somehow identify an unoccupied slot in the array, you can use special values. For example, making `int?[] data`, you can store `var item = data[front]; data[front] = null` before `Dequeueing`. Or, you can use a routine like `GetQueueData` to return all the elements in the `Queue` as a separate `IEnumerable`

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetQueueData() {
    for (int i = first, cnt = 0; cnt < counter; i = (i + 1) % size, ++cnt)
        yield return data[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The array named data will remain in the same state as when you created it as you have not done anything to make this otherwise.